# SQL Query takes to long to return data

Tags: sql, oracle

Looking for a better way to write this query and my SQL skills aren't great, basic really so looking for any pointers to make this better. This is only the first two columns and the full report will have a further 10.

I'm taking a specific set of repair types and doing analysis on them with counts and calculations. The 1st is jobs brought forward to the current financial year and the second is total amount of jobs currently received.

```
SELECT
    "Type",
    (
        SELECT
            NVL (COUNT(jjo.jjobno), 0)
        FROM
            jjobh jjo
        WHERE
            jjo.jclcode = 'L'
        AND jjo.jstatus <> '6'
        AND jjo.year_rec <> (
            SELECT
                sub_code
            FROM
                code_table
            WHERE
                main_code = 'YEAR'
        )
        AND (
            week_comp IS NULL
            OR year_comp = (
                SELECT
                    sub_code
                FROM
                    code_table
                WHERE
                    main_code = 'YEAR'
            )
        )
        AND jjo.jrepair_type = "Type"
    ) AS "B/F",
    (
        SELECT
            NVL (COUNT(jjo.jjobno), 0)
        FROM
            jjobh jjo
        WHERE
            jjo.jclcode = 'L'
        AND jjo.jstatus <> '6'
        AND jjo.year_rec = (
            SELECT
                sub_code
            FROM
                code_table
            WHERE
                main_code = 'YEAR'
        )
        AND jjo.jrepair_type = "Type"
    ) AS "Recvd"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            rep.repair_type_code AS "Type"
        FROM
            repair_type rep
        WHERE
            rep.client = 'L'
        AND rep.work_centre = '004682'
        ORDER BY
            rep.repair_type_code
    )
ORDER BY
    "Type";
```

Comment: One thing you can look at is replacing your numerous subqueries with joins. This should considerably speed up your query.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at that.

Comment: Does the table "code_table" have duplicate entries

Comment: The code_table doesn't have duplicates as far as I'm aware. I'm using that  so I don't have to hardcode the year value as the code_table holds the current year as a value that gets updated. Hopefully meaning I won't have to return to this in a years time.

Comment: The presence of this query `SELECT sub_code FROM code_table WHERE main_code = 'YEAR'` and your comment "...the code_table holds the current year as a value..." indicate a bad code smell to me. I'm guessing your `code_table` table is a Massively Unified Code-Key (MUCK), or One True Lookup, table. These should be avoided. If you don't want to have to update the "current" year each time look in to using a Calendar table with the current date from a system call.

Comment: Yes Tony the code_table is a One True Lookup set up with at lot of static values, year no, week no etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess.  I suspect you want something like:

```
SELECT jjo.jrepair_type, count(*) as valbf
FROM (SELECT coalesce(COUNT(jjo.jjobno), 0)
      FROM jjobh jjo cross join
           (SELECT sub_code
            FROM code_table
            WHERE main_code = 'YEAR'
           ) sc
      WHERE jjo.jclcode = 'L' AND
            jjo.jstatus <> '6' AND
            jjo.year_rec <> sc.sub_code AND
            (week_comp IS NULL OR
             year_comp = sc.sub_code
            ) 
     ) jjo join
     (SELECT rep.repair_type_code AS "Type"
      FROM repair_type rep
      WHERE rep.client = 'L' AND
            rep.work_centre = '004682'
     ) rtc
     on jjo.jrepair_type = rtc.repair_type_code
group by jjo.jrepair_type;
```

It looks like you want to join the "jjo" table to the "repair type code" table, producing information about each repair type.  The order by in the subquery is useless.

My suggestion is to move the "jjo" table to the outer "from".  You should also move the WHERE clauses to the outermost WHERE clause (which I didn't do).  I haven't quite figured out the date logic, but this might get you on the right track.

Comment: Gordon yes that is correct _"It looks like you want to join the "jjo" table to the "repair type code" table, producing information about each repair type"_ I'll have a go with your suggestion and let you know. I'm now starting to realise how weak my SQL skills are. Thanks